# NA as a result to pmin in R

Tags: r, dplyr, vectorization

I am using the function `pmin` in order to do a rowwise operation on a data frame.

I am conditioning on two columns which could both be NA.

My command is:

```
ifelse(is.infinite(pmin(A, B, na.rm = T))| pmin(A, B, na.rm = T)>60, 10, 0)
```

It says that if either both are NA or the minimum of the two is larger than 60, the result is 10, otherwise zero.

Usually this works fine with pmin, except when both A and B are NA, in which case I am getting NA rather than TRUE. This does not happen with regular min - but I can't use this operator on a data frame because it is not vectorized (i.e. just gets the GLOBAL minimum of this column).

How can I get TRUE as the output in this case?

Comment: Why are you using `is.infinite` instead of just `is.na`?

Comment: you are right! Because `min` gives Inf... but apparently pmin gives NA! Thanks @nicola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this without an `ifelse`.  After getting the `pmin`, `replace` the NA elements on the logical vector with `FALSE` and multiply with 10 so that FALSE returns 0 while TRUE becomes 10

```
library(dplyr)
10 * replace_na((pmin(A, B, na.rm = TRUE) > 60), FALSE)
```

---

Or after the `pmin`, do a `pmax` with 0, and `na.rm = TRUE`.   This way the `NA` elements are replaced by 0 (assuming to have only positive numbers), convert to logical (`> 60`) and multiply by 10 (as before)

```
10 * (pmax(0, pmin(A, B, na.rm = TRUE), na.rm = TRUE) > 60)
```

#### data

```
A <- c(NA, 65, 32, NA)
B <- c(NA, NA, 63, 23)
```